# How to modify a string of values in bash?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell

I have an array of strings. These strings contain values in the format of an (x,y) coordinate pair, e.g. string one contains "42,37", string two contains "54,17", and so forth. How can I modify this array of strings such that "42,37" becomes "+42+37", "54,17" becomes "+54+17", and so on?

I'm rather new to bash and writing a simple utility, I've racked my brain over this issue for the past day.

Comment: Why is this tagged both JavaScript and bash?

Comment: I typed "script" and I must have accidentally selected JavaScript from the drop-down menu, my apologies

Answer (score 0):

With bash, after the for loop new_array will contain your desired format.

```
a=("42,37" "54,17")

x=0
for i in "${a[@]}"; do
   b=${a[$x]}
   new_array[$x]="+${b:0:2}+${b:3:2}"
   ((x++))
done
```

Output:

```
for i in "${new_array[@]}"; do echo $i; done
+42+37
+54+17
```

Comment: This works but since my array contains coordinates with 3-4 digits as well, it didn't work perfectly with my solution. This solution makes much more sense to me though, thank you!